# Creating and chaining LinkedList in for loop

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to create a new `LinkedListNode` object as I parse through a `char[]` in reverse. Then I want to link these

```
    char[] totalnum = (total + "").toCharArray();
    for (int i = totalnum.length; i > 0; i--) {
        LinkedListNode sum = new LinkedListNode(totalnum[i]);
        sum.next = null;
    }
```

Here is my `LinkedListNode` class:

```
public class LinkedListNode {
    int data;
    public LinkedListNode next;

    // constructor
    public LinkedListNode(int newData) {
        this.next = null;
        this.data = newData;
    }
}
```

I was wondering how can I go about doing this. I am new to Java so this has gotten me stumped! I know I should create a new `LinkedListNode` object in each iteration but that is as far as I have gotten

Comment: sorry I htought i finished!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class LinkedListNode {
    int data;
    private LinkedListNode next;

    public LinkedListNode(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void setNext(LinkedListNode next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public LinkedListNode getNext() {
        return next;
    }
}

char[] totalNum = (total + "").toCharArray();
int length = totalNum.length;

LinkedListNode tail /*or 'head', whatever suits you*/ = new LinkedListNode(totalNum[length - 1]);
LinkedListNode newNode;
LinkedListNode previousNode = tail;

for (int i = length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
    newNode = new LinkedListNode(totalNum[i]);
    previousNode.setNext(newNode);
    previousNode = newNode;
}
```

Comment: My char array is `7550`. However when I tried your code I am getting the output 48,48,53,53 as my linked list when i return tail

Comment: well, it should be 48, 53, 53, 55 which are ASCII codes for 0, 5, 5, 7 respectively. How are you finally printing your linked list? Also, I'm sorry, the `length` variable should be `totalNum.length` (without parentheses basically) updated answer.